# Can multiple ProgIDs point to the same ClsID?

Tags: windows, com, com-interop, ole, progid

I am working on a set of what are essentially plugins, which are COM servers. Each plugin has a set of configuration data which is managed by another component, the primary key to the configuration data is the plug-in's ProgID. When the plugin needs to access a configuration item, it makes a call and passes in its ProgID and the name of the property required. This is a legacy design and I must maintain backward compatibility.

I now have a requirement to load multiple instances of each plugin, with each instance having a different set of configuration data. The solution I'm considering is to create multiple unique ProgIDs for each plugin, each ProgID would point to the single ClsId for the plugin. Thus, each instance of the plugin would be indentified by its ProgID, the ProgID is still used as the primary key for the configuration data and everything is 100% backward compatible.

So, the questions:

1. Is this an acceptable technique? (multiple ProgIDs all pointing to a single ClsID).
2. When my plugin loads, would it be able to tell which ProgID was used to create it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prog ids are typically used in two ways: to detect a class id corresponding to a prog id (CLSIDFromProgID() function) - this is used to later call CoCreateInstance() - and to detect a prog id for a given class id - this is usually used to display a human-friendly version of a class id.

Those mappings imply that there's a HKCR{ProgId}\CLSID key with a default value equal to the class id and a HKCR\CLSID{classid}\ProgID key with a default value equal to the ProgId, which means that the mapping is one-to-one. You will just not be able to have more than one prog id under one class id.

A COM component is loaded by calling CoCreateInstance() which is passed a class id - obtained by any means possible, using CLSIDFromProgID() included. There're no ways for a component to tell how the class id was obtained.

Comment: +1 for a great response, this may well eventually become the accepted answer unless anyone wants to add anything in the next few days.